# Can UISpringTimingParameters have an inverse spring effect?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiviewanimation, uiviewpropertyanimator

After dabbling with UIViewPropertyAnimator, I've found that .isReversed simply plays the animation backwards like a movie in reverse. Is it possible to apply "springiness" to the reverse animation through a custom Cubic Timing Parameter that only applies to the animation if it's reversed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to reverse the animation and go back with spring effect, you can simply use the following code snippet:

```
// prepare new timing parameters with the desired springiness
let newTimingParameters 
     = UISpringTimingParameters(dampingRatio: 0.5, initialVelocity: CGVector(dx: 2, dy: 0))

// pause the animator
propertyAnimator.pauseAnimation()

// reverse it
propertyAnimator.isReversed = true

// and restart it using new timing parameters with springiness
propertyAnimator.continueAnimation(withTimingParameters: newTimingParameters, durationFactor: propertyAnimator.fractionComplete)
```